# special characters with sed

Tags: url, sed, character

I'm trying to cut the URL out of a web link

Say for example, I want take  http://site.com/path/to/site.html to just print out 'site.com' or 'http://site.com'

This is the closest I can figure out but it's not working right:

```
echo "https://site.com/shisad/sadh" | sed -n "s/.*\(http.*\/\).*/\1/p"
```

which prints:  https://site.com/shisad/

It's something I'm doing wrong with the special character '/" I think. Any ideas ?

Comment: put the right command in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. When you're using `sed` to match path names, or other patterns containing slashes, use a character other than slash to delimit the regular expression; it makes life a lot easier.
2. The `.*` pattern is greedy; it matches the longest possible string.  You want a more constrained expression.

To print out `http://site.com`, you might use:

```
sed -n 's%.*\(https\{0,1\}://[^/]*\).*%\1%p'
```

To print out `site.com`, you might use:

```
sed -n 's%.*https\{0,1\}://\([^/]*\)/.*%\1%p'
```

If you think you might have a site without the slash after the host name (so the input only contains `http://site.com`), then you could use:

```
sed -n -e 's%.*https\{0,1\}://\([^/]*\)/.*%\1%p' \
       -e 's%.*https\{0,1\}://\([^/]*\)$%\1%p'
```

Note that these accept all sorts of punctuation characters as 'valid'; you can be more discriminating if you wish using, perhaps, `[-a-zA-Z0-9_.]*` in place of `[^/]*` — but beware internationalized domain names.  The two pattern version doesn't stop at a blank after the URL; it would include the close parenthesis of `(http://example.com)`.  This is a corollary of the point about which characters are valid.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "https://site.com/shisad/sadh"|awk -F/ '{print $1"//"$2$3}'
```

Comment: This is very straight forward!  Any downsides to this ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using `GNU sed`.

```
echo "https://site.com/shisad/sadh" | sed -r 's%.*(https://[^/]*).*%\1%'
https://site.com
```

To get just the domain name, you can simply to change the location of the storing parentheses:

```
echo "https://site.com/shisad/sadh" | sed -r 's%.*https://([^/]*).*%\1%'
site.com
```

You can of course do what you want with a simple perl `grep`:

```
echo "https://site.com/shisad/sadh" | grep -oP 'https://[^/]*'
https://site.com
```